# Creating random words from a list in order

Tags: java, random

I tried to create a programme that will generate random 6 characters long words in a specific order, meaning vovels on 1,3 and fifth position and consonants on 2,4,6. What i tried to do was :

```
import java.util.*; 
public class GenerateWords {

static String[] consonant = {"q","w","r","t","p","s","d","f"
                                ,"g","h","j","k","l","z","x",
                                          "c","v","b","n","m"}; //0-19
static String[] vovel = {"a","e","y","u","i","o"};//0-5

public static void main(String[] args) {
    static String st = new String(" ");
    static int x=0;
    static int y=0;
    static String word;
    static int generator;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<3;)
        {
            Random generator = new Random();
            generator = generator%19;   
            word = StringBuffer(st).insert(x, consonant[generator]).toString();
            x++;
            Random generatora = new Random();
            generatora = generatora%5;
            word = StringBuffer(st).insert(y, vovel[generator1]).toString();
            y++;
        }
        System.out.println(word); 
    }
}
```

I just started learning java yesterday and I'm pretty lost. Thanks for all the help with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class Random provides a random generator, not a random number :
To generate a random number you can call this:

```
Random generator = new Random();  
int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(20);  // this will generate an integer between 0 and 20
```

Additionally you can reuse the same `generator` to generate other numbers. So you don't need the `Random generatora` instance.

As @Andy already pointed out there are some more issues in your code. But let's have a look:

You already prepared the `String word` where you will store your result. Since it is *only* a String you may want to instantiate it with an empty value (not null) so you won't get some surprising `NullPointerException`:

```
String word = "";
```

As I said earlier, you only need one `Random generator` instance so lets move it *before* the `for` loop, otherwise it would create 3 Instances:

```
Random generator = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

The loop is good. You only need to count to 3. But for `i` to increment.. you actually need to increment it. Otherwise your loop-condition will never be meet and it loop infinitely.

This method will return a random integer between `0` and `max`. So you only need to define a `max` value

```
generator.nextInt( max );
```

Now, you have 19 consonants and 5 vowels. But regardless how many letters are in your arrays, you can get the arrays size by calling

```
consonant.length;
```

That way you don't have to "know" how many letters there are in your array (imagine one day you want to switch to another alphabet)

I think now you can see where I am going with this and how to get a random item from an array with a fixed length :)

But where to put it? Your idea with `StringBuffer` is admirable but way too complicated for my taste. A word you generate will look like this, right? :

dawuci

some consonant, a vowels, consonant, vowel ....  so basically its like having an empty word and adding one by one a consonant, a vowel, a consonant....

You already have your *empty* `String word` and you have your for-loop. You don't need more, just `letter + letter + letter + letter + letter + letter` and you have your word with 6 letters.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of issues here. Try this and see if you can make it work from here.

```
static String[] consonant = {"q","w","r","t","p","s","d","f"
        ,"g","h","j","k","l","z","x",
        "c","v","b","n","m"}; //0-19
static String[] vovel = {"a","e","y","u","i","o"};//0-5


for(int i=0;i<3;)
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    int random1 = generator.nextInt(19);
    word = new StringBuffer(st).insert(x, consonant[random1]).toString();
    x++;
    Random generatora = new Random();
    int random2 = generatora.nextInt(5);
    word = new StringBuffer(st).insert(y, vovel[random2]).toString();
    y++;
}
System.out.println(word);
```

}